Error descriptions not displayed in Android Studio
I've just switched to Android Studio and started developing a Flutter application. However, when I have an error in a code there's no information on the bottom displayed. Usually, either in PyCharm or Intellij short error description was displayed.
Now, to figure out what's wrong I need to click Command + F1 and then eventually pop up is displayed. The second option is to click top right side of the screen to have a summary of the errors, but that's no what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to restore the functionality like it's in PyCharm?


It looks like your PyCharm is an older version of IntelliJ. Try transposing the bottom-left (vertical) toolbar to display Git, TODO. Problems, etc. horizontally (in tabs).

Eh, for anyone wondering, it turned out that you can disable "New UI" which was released in 2024.
The solution is simply to:

From the main menu, navigate to File | Settings | Plugins | Marketplace
Search for classic ui
Click the Install button
Restart the IDE to get the old UI back

Full answer can be found here

Click on the (!) icon on the left to display description of all errors in the file:

(encircled in blue)

Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm aware of that feature, but I'm missing a one-line summary of the error I'm pointing on (like on the screenshot with white background).
